# A formula for an alternating choose sum

Tags: combinatorics

I was working on a problem for a former colleague who wanted to know the average number of points in a matching test by guessing, i.e. a test where you have to match each member of a list of items to one in another list and you get a point for each correct guess.
It turned out that it was $1$ point independent of how long the lists were which was quite surprising to me and I've proven it for odd numbers but for even numbers I have it down to proving that

> $$2\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(-1)^{m-{\frac n2-1}}\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n!}{((n/2)!)^2}$$

If this is true that's equally surprising to me and I've tried doing an induction over even $n$ but I get a nasty factor in the sum. Anyone know if this has been solved before or have a good idea of how to solve it? I'm more of an analysis guy so I'm in pretty deep water here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Consider the well-known binomial identity

> $$\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m\binom nm=0$$

This sum can be splitted up

$$\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m\binom nm=\sum_{m=0}^{n/2-1} (-1)^m\binom nm+(-1)^{n/2}\binom n{n/2}+\sum_{m=n/2+1}^n (-1)^m\binom nm=0$$

Now note that we got the following identities of the binomial coefficient

> $$\binom nm = \binom n{n-m}~~\text{ and }~~\binom {2n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

Can you finish it from hereon? Or shall I add a complete solution?

Comment: Perfect, I was effectively trying to prove that binomial identity because at an earlier step that's exactly what I had. You wouldn't happen to have an idea for a reference on it?

Comment: Regarding the first identity I gave here; I would try to look at the Wikipedia Page of the binomial coefficient for instance. Anyway it is not the hard to prove: Consider the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^n$, which can be done by using the Binomial Theorem, and plug in $x=1$ in the series as well as in the original term which directly gives you the first identity.